# Sum between rows mysql select

Tags: php, mysql

I have table like this:

```
id    |   customer_id | location_id | brand_id   | quantity
1           123             1            1            3
2           124             2            1            1
3           125             1            2            2
4           126             2            2            1
5           127             1            2            1
6           128             2            2            1
```

I want results like this:
Group by location_id and each brand_id quantity total

```
id    |   customer_id | location_id | brand_id   | quantity
1           123             1            1            3
3           125             1            2            2
5           127             1            2            1
-------------------------------------------------------
total                                    1            3
                                         2            3

2           124             2            1            1
4           126             2            2            1
6           128             2            2            1
-------------------------------------------------------
total                                    1            1
                                         2            2
```

Comment: can you format that properly

Comment: formatted @nogad

Comment: What exactly you want to sum? i see you want to order the elements via location_id! use `ORDER BY location_id ASC` in your query. i hope it helps you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. For tips on how to ask a great question, please take a look at the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: group by location_id and sum each brand_id quantity @MohammedAlhanafi

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [`SUM()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_sum.asp) Function in MySQL

```
SELECT SUM(THE-COLUMN-YOU-WANT-TO-SUM)
FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

So lets try in your table,

```
SELECT SUM(quantity)
FROM orders;
```

This will print `9` its SUMMATION for all elements in `quantity`

If you want to fetch the data for a specific name you can use AS like this,

```
SELECT SUM(quantity) AS NEW_NAME
FROM orders;
```

Ok now you want to sum a specific Columns, just use `WHERE`

like this one

```
SELECT SUM(quantity) AS newquantity
FROM orders
WHERE location_id=1 AND brand_id=1;
```

Hope this helps,
Regards.